# Ho do I access an arrayList (that is stored in main class) from another class?

Tags: java, file-io, arraylist, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

My goal is to read from and write objects into file (using file I/O). These objects are userinput (name, int value, double value etc..) stored in a dynamic `arrayList`. The `arrayList` is declared in my main class. As an further improvement of my program, I want to save those data in a file, I have created another class `ReaderWriter` in order to implement `file I/O`.

*Now how can I get reference of `arrayList` in `ReaderWriter` class?*

My application is quite big. I will show a portion of it that is related to my issue:

main:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("WELCOME TO OUR BANK!\n\n");

        List<BankAccount> bankAccounts = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();
}
```

class for getter and setter:

```
public class BankAccount {

private String name;
private int accNum;
private double initiateAmount;

//constructor
public BankAccount() {

    this.name = null;
    this.accNum = 0;
    this.initiateAmount = 0;

}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
.........................
.......................
     ............
```

ReaderWriter:

```
public void writeToFile(){


    try {
        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Jabir Al Fatah\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\BankFile.txt");
        ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject();//take the arrayList variable
        oos.close();
        fos.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

public void readFromFile(){
    try {

        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Jabir Al Fatah\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\BankFile.txt");
        ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        //make an arrayList to get those object back
        //arrayList

        ois.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Comment: Send it as a parameter or send a reference in the constructor?

Comment: user489041, was it a question or comment?

Answer (score 5):

You give your writeToFile methode an argument which has the ArrayList type. Now you create an instance of ReaderWriter in the main and use the methode writeToFile. In readFromFile you have to add a return statement which is also from type ArrayList. Now you can use the methode to fill ArrayList instance.

Correct Code:

```
public void writeToFile(ArrayList<BankAccount> accounts){


    try {
        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Jabir Al Fatah\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\BankFile.txt");
        ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(accounts);
        oos.close();
        fos.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

public ArrayList<BankAccount>readFromFile(){
    try {

        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Jabir Al Fatah\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\BankFile.txt");
        ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        //make an arrayList to get those object back and return the list


        ois.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Main:

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("WELCOME TO OUR BANK!\n\n");

            List<BankAccount> bankAccounts = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();
ReaderWriter rw = new ReaderWriter();
rw.writeToFile(bankAccounts);
List<BankAccount> bankAccounts2 = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();
bankAccounts2 = rw.readFromFile();


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass it in:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("WELCOME TO OUR BANK!\n\n");

    List<BankAccount> bankAccounts = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();

    ReaderWriter rw = new ReaderWriter(bankAccounts);
}
```